# How to get row count of select statement inside stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have requirement where I want get row count of select statement inside stored procedure  and if row count is equal to  0 then only it will execute the next statement

```
select A, B, C 
from AT 
where B = 1
```

If the above statement returns any rows, then it will not execute further but if this statement do not have any row then it will execute next statement. I have tried it using in two ways

1. `@@rowcount` - it's not working properly
2. Using temp table by inserting select statement into table getting row count of table but using temp table is not optimize way

Is there any solution?

Comment: is there any thing wrong in this question ?why -1 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select A,B,C from AT where B=1) 
BEGIN
   -- sth
END
```

---

> *is there any solution like getting into variable without hitting to database again and again*

```
DECLARE @my_rowcount INT;
select A,B,C from AT where B=1;
SET @my_rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;   -- immediately after select get @@ROWCOUNT

...
IF @my_rowcount = 0 
BEGIN
   -- sth
END
```

**EDIT:**

> *@@ROWCOUNT Globle variable for database so it may return wrong Value if any other select statement processed in other sp in same databe*

Nope. [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.**

You could easily check it with your SSMS(open 2 tabs, select 1 and 2 rows on each of them and then get @@ROWCOUNT respectively).

Comment: is there any solution like getting into variable without hitting to database again and again .........................

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT Globle variable for database so it may return wrong Value if any other select statement processed in other sp in same databe